# Trying to build a Forgot Password VB Form. Getting an error 'Cannot set CommandText while a DataReader is active'

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

Below is my code from the Visual Basic form. I am just trying to learn Visual Basic. If someone could help me out with what's wrong with my code that would be great. I tried several different methods as well, but my Update query seems to have some major issues. Just to clarify a bit more, my database table has the following columns: MemberId,FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, City, State, ZipCode, Email, Password

```vb
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class ForgotPass
Public Sqlconn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source = elibrary.db")

Public Function Hasconnection() As Boolean
    Try
        Sqlconn.Open()
        Sqlconn.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False

    End Try
End Function

Public MemberId As String
Dim MemberFirstName As String
Dim MemberLastName As String
Dim MemberAddress As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    LoginForm.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitBtn.Click
    If Hasconnection() = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successful Connection")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful")
    End If

    Dim sqlcmd2 As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Member WHERE (FirstName = '" & FirstNametxt.Text & "' and LastName = '" & LastNametxt.Text & "' and StreetAddress = '" & StreetAddresstxt.Text & "' )", Sqlconn)

    Sqlconn.Open()
    Dim sqlreader As SQLiteDataReader = sqlcmd2.ExecuteReader()

    If sqlreader.Read() = True Then
        MemberId = sqlreader("MemberId").ToString()
        MemberFirstName = sqlreader("FirstName").ToString()
        MemberLastName = sqlreader("LastName").ToString()
        MemberAddress = sqlreader("StreetAddress").ToString()
        MessageBox.Show("Select successful" & "  " & MemberId & "  " & MemberFirstName & "  " & MemberLastName)
        Sqlconn.Close()

        Sqlconn.Open()
        If MemberFirstName = FirstNametxt.Text AndAlso MemberLastName = LastNametxt.Text AndAlso MemberAddress = StreetAddresstxt.Text Then

            sqlcmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Member SET Password = '" & RetypeNewPassTxt.Text & "' WHERE FirstName = " & MemberFirstName & " AND LastName = " & MemberLastName & ""
            MessageBox.Show("Password Changed!")

            'Me.Hide()
            'ChangePasswordForm.Show()

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Information Incorrect. Please try again.")


        End If

    End If
```

I you have a link that could show me an example of a Forgot Password form that would be great too.
Thank you

Comment: Use a different command object for the update sqlcmd2. Consider wrapping all your connections, commands and readers in Using statements to ensure they are opened and closed safely.

Comment: Please don't use `vba` tags for `vb.net` questions.

Comment: a) use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings for SQL b) You dont really need the SELECT half of that snippet c) at a minimum close the reader  d) your code wont do anything because you dont execute the UPDATE query  e) never ever store passwords as plaintext